# Will intel mkl sparse BLAS coogemv internally change coo to csr storage?

Tags: sparse-matrix, blas, intel-mkl

There is sparse version of BLAS in intel MKL, for example doing multiplication of matrix and vector, we could use

`mkl_?coogemv`

> Computes matrix-vector product of a sparse general matrix stored in
>   the coordinate format with one-based indexing

But I heard that multiplication is much more efficient when doing in CSR storage.

However to generate CSR storage sparse matrix is a headache, it is much easy and understandable to generate a COO storage sparse matrix.

What I want to know is that: **Will MKL change the COO storage to CSR storage internally when using `coogemv`?** The documentation didn't say.

Comment: I have no idea what mkl does internally, but I think you should take the time to transfer data to csr format, it is not that difficult and you will be pleased with all the libraries that use csr matrices intrinsically :)

Comment: Also, if I remember correctly, mkl also provides a greater variation of algorithms for csr matrices.

Comment: @zeroth thank you for your advice